# JavaScript Regexp to simulate echo statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been messing around with this for a few hours but I can't seem to crack it. I'm basically trying to create a js Regexp that is similar to php's echo(without the parameters). Here are the patterns, and the values I am attempting to get.

```
var reg = /echo +[^\s(].+[//"';]/;

'echo "test";'.match(reg);              //echo "test";
'echo test'.match(reg);                 //echo test
'echo "test me out"; dd'.match(reg);    //echo "test me out"
'echo "test me out" dd'.match(reg);     //echo "test me out"
'echo test;'.match(reg);                //echo test;
'echo "test "'.match(reg);              //echo "test "
"echo 'test'".match(reg);               //echo 'test'


//These should all return null
'echo (test)'.match(reg);
'/echo test'.match(reg);
'"echo test"'.match(reg);
"'echo test'".match(reg);
```

I've done up an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4HS63/

Comment: Simulate? Being simlar? What a regexp does is *match strings*, nothing else. Are you asking for "*a regex to match echo statements*"?

Comment: That is precisely what I am after.

Comment: Your first example has an inconsistency. You give it the string `echo "test";` and say it should return `"test;"`. Did you mean for the input to be `echo "test;"`, or for the output to be `"test"`? **Edit** never mind, I see that's just a comment on the right, nothing important.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Yep typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex both matches what you want *and* captures the text that is being searched for:

```js
var reg = /^[\t ]*echo +(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)"|(\w+))/;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/Gz922/)

For example, `'echo "test"'.match(reg)` will return `["echo "test"", undefined, "test", undefined]`, and you can use `theMatch[2]` to get a string containing `test`.

However, the first, second, or third capture could be used, depending on the style of quotes. I don't know how to make them all use the same capture without using [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which JavaScript doesn't support.

Comment: Thankyou, you are a scholar and a gentleman. I forgot one more test, Is there a way to allow for tabs or spaces before the echo?

Comment: What about `/…('|"|)(.+?)\1/`?

Comment: @GrantKiely Sure; see the updated regex. I just added `[\t ]*` after the `^`. [`^` means](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the beginning of the line, `[\t ]` means either a tab or a space (using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)), and [`*` means](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) 0 or more.

Comment: @Bergi Good idea, but [that solution](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/EdX6w/) has a problem of its own. It does consolidate the captures, but it doesn’t capture all of the text when there are no quotes – `(.+?)` only matches one character in that case. For example, with `echo test`, the capture is `t`. That regex also matches `echo (test)` though it shouldn't. And changing the `.` to `\w` to fix that would break spaces inside quotes.

Comment: @Rory: Yeah, it was just a sketch of a new idea. I guess it could use lookahead for refining the captured value.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for

```
var reg = /^echo +(?:\w+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*');?/;
```

```
^        // anchor for string beginning
echo     // the literal "echo"
 +       // one or more blanks
(?:      // a non-capturing group around the alternation
 \w+     // one or more word characters ( == [a-zA-Z0-9_])
|        // or
 "[^"]*" // a quote followed by non-quotes followed by a quote
|'[^']*' // the same for apostrophes
)
;?       // an optional semicolon
```

Comment: Close! But it fails for "echo 'test'"

Comment: @GrantKiely: Oops, forgot the second `*`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern that allows escaped quotes inside quotes:

```
/^echo (?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\{2}|\\[\s\S])*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\{2}|\\[\s\S])*'|[a-z]\w*)/
```

Comment: [A jsFiddle for this answer](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/dV4ZD/). This answer works with all the test cases from the question.